# Using itsadug::gamtabs with Rmarkdown: tables do not display properly

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, gam

I want to include the output of a gam in an HTML document produced with Rmarkdown.

I can use itsadug::gamtabs to do so, supposedly.

I have this sample, that I saved to a file called test.Rmd:

`````
    ---
title: "gamtabs test"
author: "me"
date: "today"
output: html_document
---

```{r table1, echo=FALSE}
library(itsadug)

data(simdat)
# }
# NOT RUN {
# Model with random effect and interactions:
m1 <- bam(Y ~ Group+te(Time, Trial, by=Group),
          data=simdat)
summary(m1)
(gamtabs(m1, caption='Summary of m1'))
# }

````
`````

I render this file using:

```
    rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd')
```

However, my output is:

```
## % latex table generated in R 3.6.0 by xtable 1.8-4 package
## % Wed Jul 17 18:48:10 2019
## \begin{table}[ht]
## \centering
## \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
##    \hline
## A. parametric coefficients & Estimate & Std. Error & t-value & p-value \\ 
##   (Intercept) & 2.0762 & 0.0315 & 65.8720 & $<$ 0.0001 \\ 
##   GroupAdults & 3.1787 & 0.0446 & 71.3133 & $<$ 0.0001 \\ 
##    \hline
## B. smooth terms & edf & Ref.df & F-value & p-value \\ 
##   te(Time,Trial):GroupChildren & 8.9618 & 9.0008 & 3288.6381 & $<$ 0.0001 \\ 
##   te(Time,Trial):GroupAdults & 8.9871 & 9.0031 & 5860.7126 & $<$ 0.0001 \\ 
##    \hline
## \end{tabular}
## \caption{Summary of m1} 
## \label{tab.gam}
## \end{table}
```

Which is not what I want. I have tried using kable but get similar terrible results.

I know there is a simply solution to this but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to change:

1. If you want HTML output, you have to inform `gamtabs`/`xtable` about it, i.e. use `type = "HTML"`.
2. Since `gamtabs`/`xtable` produces raw HTML (or LaTeX) you need the chunk option `result = "asis"`. It makes sense to use this with a chunk that only produces the table.

Example:

````
---
title: "gamtabs test"
author: "me"
date: "today"
output: html_document
---

```{r model1}
library(itsadug)

data(simdat)
m1 <- bam(Y ~ Group+te(Time, Trial, by=Group),  data=simdat)
summary(m1)
```

table:

```{r table1, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
gamtabs(m1, caption='Summary of m1', type = "HTML")
```
````

[image]

Comment: I could not get this to work. Setting results="asis" and type="HTML" did not do anything for me.

Comment: @Pete I works for me. I have added a screen shot to my answer. What result do you get? Do you get any error messages?